# How to interpret the coefficients of a logistic regression on a proportion?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, modeling

Further to my previous [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/637575/modelling-a-proportion) , it seems that one can/should use a logistic regression to model a proportion.

How do I interpret the coefficients of a logistic regression when the outcome variable is a proportion and not binary? Is it the same interpretation as if the outcome variable was binary?

Using the example below (in `R`), if the interpretation is the same as if the outcome (`prop_survived`) was binary, I would say "*Controlling for all other variables, being a child nearly triples the odds of survival*". If that's not the appropriate interpretation what is? What would be the interpretation for the inverse logit of the coefficients?

Is there a way to have an interpretation on the "original" variable i.e. the proportion itself? Say for example the outcome variable was a proportion/scale of pain (ranging continuously from 0 (no pain) to 1 (extreme pain)), it wouldn't make much sense to say that a one unit increase in X increases the odds of pain by Z... Instead I am interested in knowing by how much does pain increase (on my 0 to 1 scale) given a one unit increase in X.

Hope this makes sense, Thanks.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- as_tibble(Titanic) %>% 
  group_by(Class, Sex, Age) %>%
  mutate(cohort_size = sum(n)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(cohort_size > 0 & Survived == "Yes") %>% 
  mutate(prop_survived = n / cohort_size)
data
#> # A tibble: 14 x 7
#>    Class Sex    Age   Survived     n cohort_size prop_survived
#>    <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>    <dbl>       <dbl>         <dbl>
#>  1 1st   Male   Child Yes          5           5        1     
#>  2 2nd   Male   Child Yes         11          11        1     
#>  3 3rd   Male   Child Yes         13          48        0.271 
#>  4 1st   Female Child Yes          1           1        1     
#>  5 2nd   Female Child Yes         13          13        1     
#>  6 3rd   Female Child Yes         14          31        0.452 
#>  7 1st   Male   Adult Yes         57         175        0.326 
#>  8 2nd   Male   Adult Yes         14         168        0.0833
#>  9 3rd   Male   Adult Yes         75         462        0.162 
#> 10 Crew  Male   Adult Yes        192         862        0.223 
#> 11 1st   Female Adult Yes        140         144        0.972 
#> 12 2nd   Female Adult Yes         80          93        0.860 
#> 13 3rd   Female Adult Yes         76         165        0.461 
#> 14 Crew  Female Adult Yes         20          23        0.870

model <- glm(
  prop_survived ~ Class + Sex + Age,
  weights = cohort_size,
  family = binomial(link = "logit"),
  data = data
)
summary(model)
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = prop_survived ~ Class + Sex + Age, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
#>     data = data, weights = cohort_size)
#> 
#> Deviance Residuals: 
#>     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
#> -4.1356  -1.7126   0.7812   2.6800   4.3833  
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept)   2.0438     0.1679  12.171  < 2e-16 ***
#> Class2nd     -1.0181     0.1960  -5.194 2.05e-07 ***
#> Class3rd     -1.7778     0.1716 -10.362  < 2e-16 ***
#> ClassCrew    -0.8577     0.1573  -5.451 5.00e-08 ***
#> SexMale      -2.4201     0.1404 -17.236  < 2e-16 ***
#> AgeChild      1.0615     0.2440   4.350 1.36e-05 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 671.96  on 13  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance: 112.57  on  8  degrees of freedom
#> AIC: 171.19
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
exp(coef(model))
#> (Intercept)    Class2nd    Class3rd   ClassCrew     SexMale    AgeChild 
#>  7.72017801  0.36128255  0.16901595  0.42414659  0.08891625  2.89082630
boot::inv.logit(coef(model))
#> (Intercept)    Class2nd    Class3rd   ClassCrew     SexMale    AgeChild 
#>  0.88532344  0.26539865  0.14457967  0.29782509  0.08165573  0.74298519
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>